# Standard single quotes for code in listings

Tags: listings, punctuation

In my code, I have curved quotes (see screenshot). Can I replace them with vertical quotes?

[image]

This is my formatting code:

```
\lstset{%
% General design
backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},   
frame=l,
% Code design
identifierstyle=\color{black},
keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
ndkeywordstyle=\color{greenCode}\bfseries,
stringstyle=\color{ocherCode}\ttfamily,
commentstyle=\color{darkgray}\ttfamily,
% Code
language={JavaScript},
tabsize=2,
showtabs=false,
showspaces=false,
showstringspaces=false,
extendedchars=true,
breaklines=true,
captionpos=b,
% line-numbers
xleftmargin={0.75cm},
numbers=left,
stepnumber=1,
firstnumber=1,
numberfirstline=true,
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `\usepackage{upquote}`?

Comment: It would be useful to put a full minimal working example up to play with, it looks like you've included more that `listings` to get this working.

Answer (score 7):

The use of `upquote` solves the problem:

```
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{listings}
```

**Thanks to G. Poore!**

Comment: This does not do the trick with `\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, openany, twoside]{book}` for me.